# Is it possible to define a "random" rabbitmq queue binding?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm envisioning a configuration in which one exchange is bound to several queues. Each of these bindings will be unique and thus targeted at particular messages. However, some, and perhaps most of the time I'd like the incoming messages to be randomly distributed among the queues. My current thought is to simply have the publisher choose the routing key at random from among the choices. That, however, requires the publisher to have some knowledge of the sort of bindings that are available. It would be better if the random selection were made at the exchange level.

Is it possible to specify a routing key such that the exchange will make a random choice from among the available queue bindings?

thanks

Comment: I am curious what the use case is for this?

Comment: The idea is to provide an exchange that users can post SQL INSERT and UPDATE queries to. The exchange will have multiple queues behind it, each of which will have a consumer attached that executes the queries against a database. The hope is to improve throughput by taking advantage of the database's threading. A random binding between the exchange and the queues will allow the incoming queries to be evenly spread across the collection of queues. This in turn will evenly distribute the queries among the database threads. So that's the thought.

Comment: If the point is that you can have many threads in a DB and you want them to handle multiple events coming from your queues. Why not have all the DB threads connect to one queue. The queue will distribute the messages to consumers in each thread in a round robin fashion.

Comment: I'll get there eventually. For the moment, the db library I'm using does not support asynchronous access to the db and so I need one process per db handle.

Comment: That still doesnt mean that you can't use my suggestion

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to define own exchange types for RabbitMQ. Thus you can build an exchange, which exactly fits your needs.
[RabbitMQ Random Exchange](https://github.com/jbrisbin/random-exchange) seems to have the behavior you request. However, I have no experience with it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll play around with this a bit to see if it provides the desired effect.